# Rails routes: problem with "scope :module"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

It might be a bit long, but I'll try to explain my problem clearly.

---

Here are my routes:

```
resources :jobs do
    scope :module => :job_scope do
        resource :company do
            resource :company_page
        end
    end
end
```

Ok, so the url to edit the company page is:
jobs/53-jobname/company/company_page/edit.

This is handled by the controller

`JobScope::CompanyPagesController << ::CompanyPagesController`

A `CompanyPage` has many `containers` (containers are polymorphic)

When I try to render the containers, I do

```
<% @containers.each do |container| %>
    <%= render container %>
<% end %>
```

Usually, it would render, for instance:

```
/notes/_note.html.erb
/galleries/_gallery.html.erb
```

But now, it renders

```
job_scope/notes/_note.html.erb
```

I dont want to have to repeat my views in any ways.

Is my only option to construct the path myself? Something like (in a helper):

```
render "#{container.class.name.underscore.pluralize}/#{container.class.name.underscore}"
```

Thanks !

Comment: you need to check this out railscasts.com/episodes/269-template-inheritance, if you are using rails 3.1

Comment: I know about template inheritance, but I dont really see how this helps me. Containers are not nested inside the scope, and I dont want them to be.

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-core/browse_thread/thread/9a5219dc05550934 <= These guys have the same problem. I dont think there is an elegant solution right now. We'd need some kind of option to prevent this behaviour...

Comment: Hello, I know has passed a lot of time, let me ask you if you have a "nice" solution, or if have monke-patched form_for / form_with. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-core/browse_thread/thread/9a5219dc05550934

These guys have the same problem. I dont think there is an elegant solution right now. We'd need some kind of option to prevent this behaviour...